# Getting the values of linked list with loops

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix, linked-list

I have to create a function who can get the value of a matrix wich take the form of a double linked list. Here is the structures of the matrix

```
 typedef struct row {
    unsigned int indiceRow;
    struct row * next;
    struct col * data;
} row;

typedef struct col{
    double value;
    unsigned int indiceColumn;
    struct col * next;
} col;

typedef struct matrix{
    int nRows;
    int nCols;
    struct row * rowFirst;
}matrix;
```

the structure matrix represent the top of the linked list and contain the total number of rows and columns and a variable row wich point to the first node of the list of row nodes. the row nodes contain the number of the row of the matrice, a variable row called next wich represent the next line of the matrix and a variable data point to another list of col nodes. Those col nodes contains the number of the column, the value at those coordonates(row,column) and the a col next. only the values different of zero have to be in the col linked list.

To get the value of a precise point of the matrix I created the function sp_get. It take a structure matrix, the line and column I'm looking for and a double variable as argument. It returns 0 when it works and update the variable double *val with the value I'm looking for.

```
int sp_get( struct matrix *mat, unsigned int rows, unsigned int col, double *val){
        row * temps = (row*)malloc(sizeof(row));
        temps = mat->rowFirst;
        while(temps->indiceRow!= rows){
            temps = temps->next;
        }

        while(temps->data!= NULL && temps->data->indiceColumn!= col && temps->data->next!=NULL){
            temps->data = temps->data->next;
        }

        if(temps->data->indiceColumn == col){
            *(val) = temps->data->value;
        }
        else{
        *(val) = 0.0;
        }

        return 0;
```

First I create a row variable to run through the matrix, then I look for the good row and then for the good column. If I can't find the good column it means that the value is 0.

When I use the function to look for one value, it works well, and always return the good value.(tempMatrix is a matrix variable and contain the linked list)

```
        double * vall =(double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
        sp_get(tempMatrix, 2, 3, vall);
```

but when I'm using the function with a double loop for I don't have the same results and I can't  not explain why...

```
double * vall =(double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
        int i;
        int j;
        for(i=1;i<=tempMatrix->nRows;i++){
            for(j=1; j<=tempMatrix->nCols;j++){
                sp_get(tempMatrix,i,j,vall);
                printf(" %f ", *(vall));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
```

[Here are the result I get with the loops](https://imageshack.com/i/exClOeEbp)

[and here are the results I should get](https://imageshack.com/i/f0PF2IgWp)

It might be a proble of memory leak, I don't know where it comes from.

Thanks in advance for  your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in `sp_get` alone the following problems abound:

**Memory the first two lines.**

Anytime you see something like this in successive lines in C:

```
ptr = malloc(...)
ptr = <something else>
```

it is *always* a memory leak.

**Updating the column header rather than simply enumerating it**

Once you find the row you seek, you then do this:

```
while(temps->data!= NULL && 
      temps->data->indiceColumn!= col && 
      temps->data->next!=NULL)
    {
        temps->data = temps->data->next;
    }
```

Ask yourself, *what is* `temps->data = ...` *actually updating?* It is changing the `temps->data` pointer to point to its own next, which means what `temps->data` pointed to prior is *gone*. That's fine if `temps->data` is a temporary pointer, *but it **isn't***. It is the `data` member in the row struct you worked so hard to find in the prior loop.

**Potential NULL pointer dereference**

You may think having this:

```
while(temps->data!= NULL && 
      temps->data->indiceColumn!= col && 
      temps->data->next!=NULL)
```

for the while-condition in your loop will harbor safety from `temp-data` being NULL for the code that follows:

```
if(temps->data->indiceColumn == col)
{
    *(val) = temps->data->value;
}
```

but if it did, then why bother with the first clause (which is correct, btw). It appears the addition of the last clause (`temps->data->next!=NULL`) was an effort to stave off crashes. That isn't the way to do it.

**Minor: Hiding type `col` with parameter `col`**

Needs little explanation. See your var names.

**Minor: There is no need to dynamically allocate the out-parameter as you're using it.**

Your code do to this:

```
double * vall =(double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
int i, j;
for(i=1;i<=tempMatrix->nRows;i++)
{
    for(j=1; j<=tempMatrix->nCols;j++)
    {
        sp_get(tempMatrix,i,j,vall);
        printf(" %f ", *(vall));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Can just as easily do this:

```
double val = 0.0;
int i, j;
for(i=1;i<=tempMatrix->nRows;i++)
{
    for(j=1; j<=tempMatrix->nCols;j++)
    {
        sp_get(tempMatrix,i,j,&val); // note address-of operator
        printf(" %f ", val);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

**Updated `sp_get`**

I'm pretty sure this is what you're trying to do. The following will return 0 if the indexed values found and retrieved, otherwise it returns -1 and the out-parameter is set to 0.0.

```
int sp_get( struct matrix const *mat, unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols, double *val)
{
    // prime to 0.0
    *val  = 0.0;
    if (!mats)
        return -1;

    // walk the row table
    struct row const *row_ptr = mat->rowFirst;
    while (row_ptr && row_ptr->indiceRow != rows)
        row_ptr = row_ptr->next;

    // leave now if we didn't find the row.
    if (!row_ptr)
        return -1;

    struct col const *col_ptr = row_ptr->data;
    while (col_ptr && col_ptr->indiceColumn != cols)
        col_ptr = col_ptr->next;

    if (!col_ptr)
        return -1;

    *val = col_ptr->value;
    return 0;
}
```

Note we modify nothing in the actual matrix, so the entire thing, including all pointers we use to index within it, can be `const` (and should be).

Best of luck.

Comment: thanks a lot i've made the changes you suggested,and it works fine! the problem was coming from the line "temp->data = temp->data->next;
I had to add a col variable to replace it and to take the data part, as you suggested! thanks again